# Why does $3$ divide the digit sum of powers of $3$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Okay I've come up with a conjecture. First off, let $f(n)$ denote the sum of the digits of a positive integer $n$. I conjecture that for all positive integers $j$, we have that
$$3|f(3^j).$$
I have checked $1\le j\le 33$ with Desmos, but I think there may be something wrong with my definition of $f(n)$ on desmos because desmos gives $f(3^{34})=98$ while wolfram gives $f(3^{34})=99$. But for $j\le33$, desmos confirms the conjecture.

To calculate with desmos I am using the following
$$f(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{b(n)}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{10^k}\right\rfloor-10\left\lfloor\frac{n}{10^{k+1}}\right\rfloor,$$ with $$b(n)=\lceil\log_{10}n\rceil+\lfloor\exp(n-10^{\lceil\log_{10}n\rceil})\rfloor.$$
If I'm not mistaken, $b(n)$ gives the number of digits of $n$.

Desmos may just be having trouble dealing with numbers as large as $3^{34}$.

Anyway, I have no clue as to why $3|f(3^j)$, as I stumbled upon it accidentally. might anyone have some insight? Thanks!

Comment: $3$ divides a natural number $n$ iff $3$ divides the digit sum of $n$.

Comment: Actually, $3\mid f(n)$ already when $n$ is a multiple of $3$. Of course, powers of $3$  (other than $3^0$) are multiples of $3$

Comment: +1 for working out an algorithm

Comment: A similar result holds for divisibility by $9$ and in general the divisibility by $b-1$ follows same rule in base $b$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $n = a_m 10^m + \cdots + a_0$, a base $10$ representation of $n$. Then $n - f(n) = a_m (10^m -1) + \cdots a_1 (10-1)$. Since $ 10 ^ i - 1 =  9 ( 1 + 10 + \cdots 10^{i-1})$ we see that  $3 \mid 10^i - 1$ for each $i \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $3 \mid n-f(n)$. If $3 \mid n $ then $3 \mid f(n)$ as well.

Comment: ah okay this works thank you

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).